# Some values not passing through $_POST from HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, post, textbox

I have some text boxes in a form- and I'm entirely confused because one of the values is being passed through but the others aren't.

the code looks like this

```
echo 'Please Check that this Report Level Information is correct<br>';
echo 'Report Key:  <input type="text" name="report_key" value="'. $info_to_print[0]->report_key.'"><br>';
echo 'Report Key:  <input type="text" name="report_title" value="'. $info_to_print[0]->report_title.'"><br>';
echo 'Report Date as Written:   <input type="text" name="date_as_written" value="'. $info_to_print[0]->date_as_written.'"><br>';
echo 'Report Date (yyyy-mm-dd): <input type="text" name="report_date" value="'. $info_to_print[0]->report_date.'"><br>';
echo 'Report Note:      <input type="text" name="report_note" value="'. $info_to_print[0]->transcription_notes .'"><br>';
echo 'Image Gallery ID:  <input type="text" name="image_gallery_id" value="'. $info_to_print[0]->image_gallery_id .'"><br>';
echo 'Report Number:   <input type="text" name="report_num" value="'. $info_to_print[0]->report_number.'"><br>';
echo 'Copied Report Key: <input type="text" name="copy_report_key" value="'. $info_to_print[0]->copied_report_key.'"><br>';
```

and on the screen it looks like this
[image: the output of the code on the screen]

So when I proceed to the next screen (which is lower in the page and not shown), what's happening is that the report key is being passed through- but all the other fields are passed through as empty strings- when that's not in the text box. I've checked this because I've used several text phrases instead of the report key (in the box) and they've all come through- but when I've put anything at all into the other text boxes they've not been passed through.

I can't figure out why the subsequent nearly identical lines of code don't work.

Comment: there must be something like a object called $info_to_print[0] that calls a method that's called the same way the POST variables are called. It makes no sense to me. post more code so we can see what's going on there

Comment: @MaxMuster Turns out, later in the function I was calling a different function which was printing values out- but for some stupid reason I put them into textboxes. And copied the names from the function here. So I was overwriting everything as blank.

Entirely my fault.

Answer (score 0):

I tested things by changing all the names of the textfields (Adding a 1 to the end of the names) - Seems that *somewhere else*, later in the code, I'm redefining those textfields (or at least textfields using the same names) as blank. So there's nothing wrong with that code as such, there's something wrong somewhere else.